# Viewer for BigTIFF images larger than 20 Gigabytes

Tags: windows, image-viewer

Does anyone know a viewer for huge [BigTIFF](http://bigtiff.org/) images larger than 20 Gb? I have enough RAM and speed capacity for it, but I can't find a viewer that supports this size of BigTIFF images. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I found ImageJ plugin [Bio-Formats](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5/users/imagej/installing.html) that supports BigTIFF and works great. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can support images up to [TetraPixel](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel) and includes a viewer but I can not be sure that it will not be necessary to downsize the image prior to viewing - it is not 100% clear on the web site.

- Libre/FLOSS
- Cross Platform

Answer (score 0):

You can use [netScope Viewer](https://www.netscope.de/), it will open the image as tiles, so the ram will unloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Image Processor](https://mircomir.blogspot.com/2021/07/image-processor.html): it opens BigTIFF and it swaps the image in a temp folder if you don't have enough memory.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/60871)